# Java - How can you call a variable inside a string using JavaScriptExecutor?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im using selenium webdriver(JAVA) on testing and I have a fire event method that should be reusable depending on the locator that is passed into it. My code is below :

```
public void fireEvent() {

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('pin').blur()");

}
```

Is there a way for this specific code to accept any element ID on the 'pin', that can make it look like :

```
public void fireEvent(String locator) {

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('{locator}').blur()");

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript code that receives "executeScript" is a regular String, you can compose this String as usual, for example:

```
public void fireEvent(String locator) {
  String jsToExecute = String.format("return document.getElementById('%s').blur()", locator​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​)​
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(jsToExecute);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might have a go

```
public void fireEvent(String elementId) {
     ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('arguments[0]').blur()", elementId);
}
```

Instead of passing string `elementId` in, you might also try pass the element itself in, so that you don't need to worry about `ById` or `ByClassName` anymore.

```
public void fireEvent(WebElement element) {
     ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].blur()", element);
}
```