# Access java variable inside selenium webdriver javascriptexecutor

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have an int variable in java like

```
int height = 10;
```

I want to use this java int type variable inside javascriptexecutor of selenium webdriver.
I have tried in some ways but it shows error all time

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("var test = '${height}';")
```

or like this

```
jse.executeScript("var test = '<%=height%>';"
```

What is the way to use this int type variable inside javascriptexecutor of selenium webdriver?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - How can you call a variable inside a string using JavaScriptExecutor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272862/java-how-can-you-call-a-variable-inside-a-string-using-javascriptexecutor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is like this:

```
int height = 10;//java variable
jse.executeScript("var test = "+height+";" //called inside executor
+ "alert('height is '+test);");  // checked that java variable in an alert works
```

finally thanks to Shubham jain for his suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `+` operator to achieve it.

Use the code below:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
int height=10;
String script="alert('"+height+" book does not exist');"; 
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript(script);
```

Comment: Dear Shubham jain, 

its return the same  error : 
.org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: height is not defined.

any other suggestion pls

Comment: FIrst of all you need to assigne the value as 10 to your int height as I had assiged in my code, I thing you have not assigned any value as 10 to your variable. If you have done this that may be your facing sometype  concat related issue. Use my updated code and let me know.

Comment: this is my code written according to your suggestion:

    int height = 10;  
    String h = "var test = '${"+height+"}';";   
    jse.executeScript("alert(h);");  

now the error is ::    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: h is not defined

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion ... and finally it works